# React.js process.env.PUBLIC_URL doesn't generate the same path depending on the route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using React-Router and I have two components accessible from `/account` and `/admin/account` respectively. On the two components I am loading the same image named `coin.png` stored in the public folder of my React project. I called the image using :

```
<img src={ process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "coin.png" }>
```

I then expected React to look for the image in the public folder but on the second component the image doesn't load and the reason is that React looks for `localhost:3000/admin/coin.png` instead of `localhost:3000/coin.png`

**Is `process.env.PUBLIC_URL`  supposed to generate a path relative to the current route or am I doing something wrong?**

I resolved the problem temporarily by using :

```
<img src={ process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "../coin.png" }>
```

but I am not sure it is the good way.